# For which $\alpha$ does $L_\alpha\models\omega_1$ is a cardinal?

Tags: set-theory

i'm reading the proof of Jech of Ketonen's theorem, that if there is a uniform nonregular ultrafilter over $\omega_1$, then Zero Sharp exists.
At some point (Lemma 38.13, (Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 79) Thomas Jech - Set theory-Academic Press,  Elsevier (1978)) he proves, that $\omega_1$ is inaccessible in L.
My Question is, for which $\alpha$ does $L_\alpha\models\omega_1^V$ is a cardinal?
I would have assumed, that this is the case for all $\alpha>\omega_1$, but in the proof it seems, that $L_{\omega_2}\models$"$\omega_1^V$ is a cardinal", but it's not always the case for $L_\gamma$ for $\omega_1<\gamma<\omega_2$.
I thought, being a cardinal is downwards absolute.
Maybe i'm just misinterpreting something in the proof.

Let D be the nonregular ultrafilter which extends the club filter and $\omega_1<\gamma<\omega_2$ s.t. $L_\gamma\prec L_{\omega_2}$. We then can define elementary embeddings $j_{\gamma}^\alpha:L_{f_\gamma(\alpha)}\to L_\gamma$ with $j_{\gamma}^\alpha(\alpha)=\omega_1$ for club many $\alpha$.

We then assume, that $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$. This means there is an $\alpha_0<\omega_1$ s.t. for all $\alpha_0<\alpha<\omega_1$ there is an $f(\alpha)<\omega_1$ s.t. $L_{f(\alpha)}\models \alpha$ is not a cardinal.

Then we get by the nonregularity of the ultrafilter, that there is a $\gamma$ s.t. $f<f_\gamma$ mod D. So for almost all $\alpha$, $L_{f_\gamma(\alpha)}\models \alpha$ is not a cardinal.

This should be a contradiction because then there is an $\alpha$ s.t we have this elementary embedding and $L_{f_\gamma(\alpha)}\models \alpha$ is not a cardinal. So $L_\gamma\models\omega_1$ is not a cardinal. Contradiction.

By this, it seems, that it's not important to have, that $L_\gamma$ is an elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_2}$.

Comment: Being a cardinal *is* downwards absolute.

Comment: And why are you reading Jech's first edition instead of the third edition?

Comment: I was told to read this edition, don't know why.

Comment: Really? By whom?

Comment: By Schindler, for a seminar.

Comment: Weird. I would think that Ralf cover something like this in his book. But oh well. I guess he knows better.

Answer (score 2):

*(Caveat lector: I do not have a copy of this specific edition of the book. I can only guess what is inside of it based on the information given in the question.)*

What does it mean for $\omega_1$ to *not* be an inaccessible in $L$? Well, it means that there is some $\alpha_0<\omega_1$ such that $(\alpha_0^+)^L=\omega_1$.

That means that for all $\alpha\in(\alpha_0,\omega_1)$, $\alpha$ is *not* a cardinal in $L$, and therefore there is some $f(\alpha)$ witnessing that.

Now using the properties of $D$, we get that for almost all $\alpha$, $f_\gamma(\alpha)$ works as an example of that.

Because $D$ extends the club filter, we can also assume that $\gamma$ is such that $L_\gamma\prec L_{\omega_2}$. Then for a club of $\alpha<\omega_1$ we have elementary embeddings $j_\gamma^\alpha\colon L_{f_\gamma(\alpha)}\to L_\gamma$ such that $j_\gamma^\alpha(\alpha)=\omega_1$. Simply take a countable elementary submodel of $L_\gamma$ with $\omega_1$ an element of the model (for simplicity we may assume it contains $\alpha_0$ as well).

But now we have a contradiction, since $L_{f_\gamma(\alpha)}\prec L_\gamma$, with $\alpha$ being mapped to $\omega_1$. But $L_\gamma\models\omega_1\text{ is a cardinal}$, while $L_\gamma\models j_\gamma^\alpha(\alpha)\text{ is not a cardinal}$.

Comment: What i meant was, that there is a contradiction wether or not $L_\gamma$ is an elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_2}$. And this should be the case, because already $L_\gamma\models\omega_1$ is a cardinal, right?

Comment: There is no contradiction. All the $L_\gamma$'s satisfy that $\omega_1$ is a cardinal. Just not all of them elementary in $L_{\omega_2}$.

Comment: Yeah but under the assumption, the $L_{f(\alpha)}\models\alpha$ is not a cardinal, but there is an elementary embedding into $L_\gamma$, which maps $\alpha$ to $\omega_1$

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question and clarify the whole thing? Maybe put some more paragraph breaks, and expand a bit about the proof you're confused about. It is really a combination of unclear and an XY problem at the moment...

Comment: I added more information about the proof. I hope it's more clear now what i mean.

Comment: Yes, it is clearer now.

Comment: Where did you need, that $L_\gamma\prec L_{\omega_2}$?

Comment: I'm not sure. My suggestion is to try and find the original proof by Ketonen. Jech is an excellent source, but he is also notorious for his telegraphic style, and that can sometimes introduce unclear proofs or even mistakes (lest we hold it against him, the book itself is an enormous undertaking and an incredibly valuable source for learning set theory).

Comment: Yeah, i think it could just be a small mistake and i myself used Jech several times and always thought it was a good read. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed right - being a cardinal is downwards absolute. In particular, if $L_\alpha$ thinks that $\beta$ isn't a cardinal, that means that there are $f,\gamma\in L_\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ thinks $\gamma$ is an ordinal $<\beta$ and $f$ is a surjection from $\gamma$ to $\beta$. But all of that data is upwards absolute: we would have in $V$ that $\gamma$ is an ordinal $<\beta$ and $f$ is a surjection from $\gamma$ to $\beta$.

It might help if you can explain *why* the proof suggests that this fails.